# Why do I need to wrap React/Enzyme state changes in act?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-dom

In my simple React/ReactDOM/Enzyme unit test I get a warning from ReactDOM about wrapping any mutations to state in `act()`. Why do I need to do this if my test passes anyway? I have 50 or so React components that all use hooks, custom hooks, etc. and I never wrap in `act()` and they all pass.

Can I just disable this warning? I don't want to add extra code for what appears to be no reason.

The warning:

```
Warning: An update to MyComponent inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */

    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at [redacted]
```

My test:

```
const App = () => {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  const myOnClick = () => {
    setIsLoaded(true);
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={myOnClick}>
      {isLoaded ? 'Yes' : 'No'}
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
describe('My test', () => {
  let wrapper

  beforeAll(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<App />)
  })

  it('renders "no"', () => {
    expect(wrapper.text()).toBe('No')
  })

  describe('When onClick is called', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      wrapper.find('div').prop('onClick')()
    })

    it('renders "yes"', () => {
      expect(wrapper.text()).toBe('Yes')
    })
  })
})
```

CodeSandbox repro: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-169-act-warning-repro-olm8o?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&previewwindow=tests

Answer (score 13):

`act()` in first place runs all related `useEffect` that would be async way otherwise. You don't see any difference since you don't have `useEffect` in your component's code

According to [Enzyme's docs](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme#reacttestutilsact-wrap) in most recent version `mount()` should be already wrapped with `act()` internally:

> If you're using React 16.8+ and `.mount()`, Enzyme will wrap apis including `.simulate()`, `.setProps()`, `.setContext()`, `.invoke()` with `ReactTestUtils.act()` so you don't need to manually wrap it.
>
> We cannot wrap the result of `.prop()` (or `.props()`) with `.act()` in Enzyme internally since it will break the equality of the returned value. However, you could use `.invoke()` to simplify the code:

````
const wrapper = mount(<SomeComponent />);
wrapper.invoke('handler')();
expect(/* ... */);```
````

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My component doesn't use `useEffect` but ReactDOM still complains so I assume using `useState` also has the same problem.

Comment: It just complains regardless of presence of useEffect hooks. It is also a good practice to not assume such implementation details in the unit test, as code may change in the future.

Answer (score 5):

The line causing the `act()` warning is

```js
wrapper.find('div').prop('onClick')()
```

As @skyboyer's answer advised `prop` is not wrapped with `act` internally. When you call the onClick and update state, react is warning that something changed unexpectedly. If you use `.simulate` instead you do not need to wrap it with `act`.

```
wrapper.find('div').simulate('click')
```